# text file string parsing reg ex python

Tags: python, regex, file

I am new to python and am not sure what I am doing wrong. My teacher recommends i keep track of each line and not to split the address. I have tried alot of methods but am not sure where to go from here. Should I try reg ex? If so how? I have never done that- I am new to Python.

**HERE IS MY ASSIGNMENT:** Using a text editor or IDE, create a text file of names and addresses to use for testing based on the following format:

```
Firstname Lastname
123 Any Street
City, State/Province/Region PostalCode
```

Include a blank line between addresses, and include at least three addresses in the file. Create a program that verifies that the file exists, and then processes the file and displays each address as a single line of comma-separated values in the form:

```
Lastname, Firstname, Address, City, State/Province/Region, PostalCode
```

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
def get_list(filename):
    addresses = []

    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.ljust(len(line[1:])) 
            line = line.split("\n")
            if line[0] == "Address Book:":
                continue 
            else:

                addresses.append(line[0])

        print(" ".join(addresses))
        #print(addresses)
        return addresses
```

**HERE IS A SAMPLE TXT FILE**

AddressBook.txt

John Doe
1234 Sunny rd.
New York, NY, 10001

Hey Jude
7608 Abby rd. 
New York, NY, 10001

Jane Doe
3583 Penny ln.
New York , NY, 10002

Comment: You shouldn't need to use regex for this use case. If the values of each line is delimited by a certain character(such as a space or comma), you can do a `.split()` and use the list positions to store the values in certain variables. Please put a sample text file as well to help replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understood what you are trying to do. Sorry I am posting this as an answer and not commenting on the question (I don't have the reputation for commenting on the question). So you have a text file that is full of lines that have a name and an address? You want to take that file and split it into names and addresses? If so, do you need the address linked to the person's name? Just clarify that for me and I will be more than glad to help!

Comment: yeah, sorry I am new to Python and programming in general. Any help is appreciated. I also just edited the question to include how our instructor wants the final view to look.

Comment: Hi, thank you for rewriting your question it is a lot clearer now! So right now what is the current output of your code? what are you struggling here with?

Comment: Currently I separated each value (fname,lname), address, and then city,state,zip. I now have them into arrays displays all the names in one list, addresses in another and city,state zip. Now I just need to figure out output for a parallel array. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Well since you are doing it that way, there is no link between the names and the addressees (what I mean by that is that you can not know who's address belong to who). However if you are doing it this way one way you can link between them is by concatenating the name, last name and the addresses if they are all in the same index of the arrays(just by running a for loop). Let me know if you need help. However a more logical solution to your problem would be while you are working on each name + address, save them directly to a new finished array and then save that array into the text file.

Comment: I hope that makes sense, please let me know if something is not clear